# please explain the dataflow in MVC specially in codeigniter

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter

Can anyone please explain me the object flow in codeigniter MVC ? I can see for example when I put the followong code in controller it works, but i am not being able to figure out which part of this goes in model in vews. I tried several ways but coudn't. When i use the example codes from other it works but myself i am getting confused. Please help

```
    $query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
   echo $row->title;
   echo $row->name;
   echo $row->body;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That would translate into something like:

Model:

```
class SomeModel extends Model {
    function SomeModel() {
        parent::Model();
    }

    function get_some_data() {
        return $this->db->query('some_query')->result_array();
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
class SomeController extends Controller {
    function SomeController() {
        parent::Controller();
    }

    function index() {
        $this->load->model('SomeModel');
        $some_data = $this->SomeModel->get_some_data();
        $this->load->view('some_view');
    }
}
```

View:

```
foreach($some_data as $data) {
    echo $data->title;
    echo $data->name;
    echo $data->body;
}
```

However, for your communication between controller and view I would recommend using a template parser such as [Dwoo](http://dwoo.org/) or [Twig](http://www.twig-project.org/) (I don't like [the one that comes with CI](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/parser.html)).

Comment: is it necessary to append the .php to the view ? E.g. `$this->load->view('some_view.php');`

Answer (score 0):

On the controller part I was doing:

```
class SomeController extends Controller {
    function SomeController() {
        parent::Controller();
    }

    function index() {
    }

    function show_data(){
            $this->load->model('SomeModel');
            $some_data = $this->SomeModel->get_some_data();
           $this->load->view('some_view.php');
           $this->index()
    }
}
```

is that not the way to do it when we have many function ? When i look at other's code I see something like that or I am wrong ?

Comment: @Pokhara: That depends on the structure of your application. I do however recommend that you only use public functions for your actual pages, and make your internal functions private. 

I'm not sure what you're trying to do there though.